# How to get full match ignoring non-digits in regex?

Tags: regex, plsql

Im trying to get number from a string ignoring all non-digits like commas, symbols etc. I have a regex like this:

```
(?:[\d]+)
```

For "45,00%", It results the following:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-2 45
Match 2
Full match  3-5 00
```

But i want full single match as 4500. How can i do that?

Comment: Replace `\D+` with empty string which will leave you with only numeric string. But if you have decimal numbers, then you will need to change the strategy a bit.

Comment: where is \D+? I dn see it in my code

Comment: No no, I am saying if you want `4500` out of `45,00%` then one way to achieve it is, replace all non-digits which is represented by `\D` with empty string.

Comment: how do i replace using regex? im not using python code here. I just want to capture the number

Comment: Please include the full value which would appear in the column, for each record.

Comment: for each record, the column should have a numeric value.

Comment: So, do you have that string as a value of a single row or 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

We can try first using `re.findall` to find all matching percentage strings, then use `re.sub` against the resulting list to strip off the decimal character:

```
input = "Here is one value 45,00% and 12% is another"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)?%', input)
matches = [re.sub(r'[,%]', '', i) for i in matches]
print(matches)

['4500', '12']
```

Comment: Im not using python for this.

Comment: Then why on Earth did you tag with Python?  And, if you're not using Python then what are you using?

Comment: Im using plsql.